# Working with JSONBuilder in Groovy/Grails

Tags: json, grails, groovy, tree

As input I have list of all objects where each object has properties:

- name
- children(object.children is the list of all children)
- parent(null if object is top level)

How correctly to use Groovy JSONBuilder to render such data(depth of tree is unlimited):

```
-Object 1
--Object 1.1
---Object 1.1.1
--Object 1.2
-Object 2
```

in JSON format it should be something like this:

```
[
    {
        "name":"Object1",
        "children":[
            {
                "name":"Object1.1",
                "children":[
                    {
                        "name":"Object 1.1.1",
                        "children":[]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name":"Object1.2",
                "children":[]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"Object2","children":[]
    }
]
```

This is needed to build JSON for extJS component which will display this tree. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this property to your *Config.groovy* file:

```
grails.converters.json.default.deep=true
```

The [Grails Doc](http://grails.org/Converters+Reference)
is a little out of date but the relevant property is listed there under 'Configuration Options'

Comment: Great! Thanks! Another small question. Is it possible to modify the properties. E.g I don't need class property or i want to add extra one.

Comment: @muffin, if you're talking about just _rendering_ fewer/additional properties, I think you'll need to do much more manual coding. Take a look at [this blog](http://manbuildswebsite.com/2010/02/08/rendering-json-in-grails-part-2-plain-old-groovy-objects-and-domain-objects/)

Answer (score 1):

Store this structure in a object say jsonContainer and try following piece of code

```
render jsonContainer as grails.converters.deep.JSON
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but It is not clear for me how actually to store such structure in object. BTW, deep converters are deprecated :(